# Is there a non-VBA Excel spilling formula to create and process arrays of arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a sheet in Excel 365 with the columns A and B as shown below and I want to get columns C and D with some formula (not VBA!). That is, I want to repeat every *Title* for *Count* times and add a running number to it.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Title** | **Count** | **Running Title** | **Running Number** |
| **2** | Anna | 3 | Anna | 1 |
| **3** | Ben | 2 | Anna | 2 |
| **4** |  |  | Anna | 3 |
| **5** |  |  | Ben | 1 |
| **6** |  |  | Ben | 2 |

For the **Running Title**, I found a [somewhat arcane formula](https://excelmee.com/excel-formulas/excel-formula-to-make-duplicates-of-every-row-n-times) that looks somewhat unstable (relying on string processing). It basically uses the following formula to create an array that is `{2,2,2,3,3}` and `XLOOKUP` on that to get the titles.

```
=XLOOKUP(
   IFERROR(
      FILTERXML(
        "<a><b>"&
        SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,REPT(ROW($A$2:$A$100)&" ",$B$2:$B$100)))," ","</b><b>")&
        "</b></a>",
        "//b"
      ),
   ""),
   ROW($A$2:$A$100),
   A2:A100
)
```

This works, but it would be great to see some less patchy formula (i.e. not relying on specifics on how Excel treats strings) for the purpose.

For the **Running Number**, I *could* use a formula like `=IF($A2<>"",IF($C1=$C2,$D1+1,1),"")` in cell D2 and extend it downwards by dragging the lower right corner downwards. This works, but I would love to see a *spilling* formula that only has to be defined in D2 and nowhere else.

In summary, is there a way to create columns C and D in the example above without having to define the size of the output (like I do by manually expanding the formula area) and without resorting to functions that depend on the internal workings of strings in Excel?

Comment: Perhaps not an improvement to what you're already doing, but [how to repeat cell value](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1897-excel-repeat-cell-value-x-times.html) would get you the running title by using 2 helper columns, then a simple COUNTIF to get the running number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the formulas:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

### Using `TEXTSPLIT()` & `TEXTJOIN()` with `REPT()`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",,REPT(A2:A3&"|",B2:B3)),"-","|",1)
```

---

Or,

### Create Custom Formula With A Friendly Name Using `LAMBDA()`

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=REPEAT.NTIMES(A2:A3,B2:B3)
```

---

The Excel `LAMBDA()` function gives us a way create custom functions that can be reused throughout a workbook, without using `VBA`, with a `friendly name`.

The formula used in **Name Manager** as shown below with testing syntax

```
=LAMBDA(values,num_repeat,
XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(num_repeat)),
VSTACK(1,SCAN(1,num_repeat,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))),
VSTACK(values,""),,-1))(A2:A3,B2:B3)
```

---

Copy the above formula, not including the testing parameters at the end, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, this opens the **Name Manager**, click **New**.

In the **New Name dialog**, enter the name <kbd>REPEAT.NTIMES</kbd>, leave the scope set to **workbook**, and paste the formula you copied into the **"Refers to"** input area, press **OK**.

Now that the `LAMBDA()` formula has a name, it can be used in the workbook like any other function.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

Lastly to get the Running Number we can use a `COUNTIF()` Function,

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)
```

---

**Edit:** 3/28/2024

• Without using any `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, SEQUENCE(,MAX(F2:F3)),
     δ, TOCOL(IFS(α<=F2:F3,E2:E3&"|"&α),2),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(δ,"|"),TEXTAFTER(δ,"|")))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=REDUCE("Running "&{"Title","Number"},A2:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(COLUMN(b)=1,LET(x,OFFSET(b,,1,1),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(b,SEQUENCE(x,,,0)),SEQUENCE(x)))),a)))
```

Or:

```
=REDUCE("Running "&{"Title","Number"},A2:A3&"|"&B2:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(x,TEXTBEFORE(b,"|"),y,--TEXTAFTER(b,"|"),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y,,,0)),SEQUENCE(y))))))
```

Or:

```
=HSTACK(REDUCE("Running Title",REPT(A2:A3&"|",B2:B3),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,,"|",1)))),REDUCE("Running Number",B2:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,SEQUENCE(b)))))
```