# Repeat values excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to repeat a value x time in rows. when it is done repeat another value n time. I found `SEQUENCE()` but it works only for the first value.

EXAMPLE:

```
Repeat in rows starting from C1
Repeat A1 value: 42
N time A2 value: 3
then Repeat B1 value: 67
M time B2 value: 5
```

In C8 I should have the last 67 value

Is there a way to concatenate the =SEQUENCE?

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv4QB.png)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 67 |
| 3 | 5 |

Comment: You could have searched the StackOverflow, same query was resolved earlier and here is the solutions given [Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181973/is-there-a-non-vba-excel-spilling-formula-to-create-and-process-arrays-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

Give a try on the following formula-

```
=TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(A1:B1&"|",A2:B2)),,"|")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXPAND()` for example:

[image]

```
=VSTACK(EXPAND(A1,A2,,A1),EXPAND(B1,B2,,B1))
```

Or go with a somewhat more expandable option:

```
=TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A2:B2))>A2:B2,x,A1:B1),3,1)
```

Comment: First One nice invention sir