# Paste Excel Data into another column based on number in another column

Tags: excel, formatting

[image: Target Result]

So basically I have a column with some data 1st column and 2nd column with numbers, which says how much of data from 1st column I need.
What I need (as shown in pic) is to create another single column with values from 1st column but if Lets say 1st column has data "A" and 2nd column has a number 2 then the result column should have 2 rows with value "A". (The attached pic should make it clear).

How do I do this in excel?

Data 1     Data 2       Result
A          2              A
A

I am stuck and not able to think of a solution here.

Comment: There are so many posts on this : **[Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181973/is-there-a-non-vba-excel-spilling-formula-to-create-and-process-arrays-of-arrays)**