# Create a list based on number of occurrences in Exc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a list based on a number of occurrences per cell like the below. Is it possible to do using formulas instead of VBA? If not, can anyone help with a VBA code for it?

[image: Example]

Table with all the cells based on the number of occurrences.

Comment: There are so many solutions over the forum, please do basic research. **[Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181973/is-there-a-non-vba-excel-spilling-formula-to-create-and-process-arrays-of-arrays)** another one **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74571119/8162520)**