# Map non-boolean vector with text vector in Excel

Tags: excel, mapping

| Variable Numbers | Fixed Text | Desired result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fixed text1 | Fixed text1 |
| 2 | Fixed text2 | Fixed text2 |
| 0 | Fixed text3 | Fixed text2 |
| 2 | Fixed text4 | Fixed text4 |
| 0 | Fixed text5 | Fixed text4 |

How do I produce a new row or column that maps text in Column text with Numbers column and results in respective number of Fixed text cells as in the Number column?

I looked at Map and Sequence functions, but struggle even to formulate how this operation could be called in Excel. Any keywords for search will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(a,FILTER(A2:B6,A2:A6>0),b,TAKE(a,,1),c,TAKE(a,,-1),TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(c&"|",b)),,"|"))
```

[image]

Answer is based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571362 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182137/11222393 . Just added `FILTER` to filter out *0* values.